# ES6 Function declaration difficulty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am taking a course on React Native and realize that the instructor declares functions in two different ways, for seemingly no different reasons. Please explain when each function declaration should be used:

```
example = () => ();
```

vs

```
example = () => {};
```

Thank you

Comment: this `example = () => {};` needs a `return` inside in order to return something, otherwise it just executes code. 
this `example = () => ();` will directly return the expression inside round brackets

Comment: Basically, the first syntax specifies return value, second syntax executes code like any ordinary function. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions can differ in [function bodies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) (Thanks Robbie). The *concise* function body can only consist of a single expression which is evaluated and implicitly returned. The conventional *block* function body requires the `return` keyword or it will return `void`.

```
example1 = () => 1 + 1;

example2 = () => {
    const result = 1 + 1;
    return result;
};

example3 = () => { 
    const result = 1 + 1;
};
```

`example1()` has a concise body and will *implicitly* return the result of the expression `2`.
`example2()` has a block body and does *explicitly* return `2`.
`example3()` has a block body and *no explicit* return, therefore it returns `void`.

Note that the normal braces `()` around a *concise* function body are required if you want to return an object literal:

```
example = () => ({some: 'object'});
```

Comment: here's a link to the MDN docs with this concept explained: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body